# MQTT does not connect at all, always disconnects

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, mqtt

I have been trying to connect mqtt to my mqtt Server using 3.1, but i am unable to do so. here is my code :
i am using Cocoa MQTT for this:

```
mqtt = CocoaMQTT(clientID: clientId, host: server, port: UInt16(port))
mqtt.username = ""
mqtt.password = password
self.mqtt.delegate = self
mqtt.connect()
```

Only disconnect and status change delegate called, other delegates never get called.
When I set loglevel to debug

it only prints:

**CocoaMQTT(info): Connected to 18.194.27.95 : 8000
CocoaMQTT(debug): Socket write message with tag: 0**

and only status change and disconnect delegate get called.

Comment: i am facing the same problem, always disconnect delegate method gets called.

Comment: And the logs from the MQTT broker show?

Comment: Yes always shows that logs

CocoaMQTT(info): Connected to 18.194.27.95 : 8000
 CocoaMQTT(debug): Socket write message with tag: 0

Comment: Please edit the question to show the logs from the broker, not the client

Comment: In lieu of the broker logs, a wireshark capture of unencrypted packets would diagnose your problem. Lesson #1: ALWAYS get the simplest scenario to work. The simplest scenario is unencrypted communications that can be captured and diagnosed with a packet sniffer.